# Content Missing when XML file uploaded via .net Service

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, file-upload

I am uploading an xml file via asp.net web service to the web server. It is similar to a restful web service. I have observed that sometimes only partial data is uploaded. Only half of the content is uploaded. The file size is approx 90 KB and in rare cases the size drops to 3-5 KB.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ".NET service" is (to me) a bit vague. Do you know if it's a WCF service/ashx/... receiving the upload?

Comment: Its a simple web service implemented with REST!

Comment: You'll most likely need to show the code involved, "REST" can be implemented in multiple ways in .NET so any attempt to a solution is currently just total guesswork.